# Send XML to URL

Tags: excel, vba

I am using below code to send XML to a URL

```
'Send XML to OTM
        'Dim oXmlHttp As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
        'Set oXmlHttp = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
        Dim oXmlHttp As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
        Set oXmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
        With oXmlHttp
            .Open "POST", "https://" & Env & "/GC3/glog.integration.servlet.WMServlet", False, User_Name, Pass_Word
            .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/xml"
            .setRequestHeader "Connection", "Keep-Alive"
            .setRequestHeader "Accept-Language", "en"

            oXmlHttp.send xmlInput
            'On Error GoTo ErrHandler:

        End With

        'Dim oXmlReturn As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
        Set oXmlReturn = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
        Dim xmlroot As IXMLDOMElement
        'Dim RefTransNum As String
        oXmlReturn.LoadXML (oXmlHttp.responseText)
        XmlRes = oXmlHttp.responseText
        'Strpos1 = InStr(XmlRes, "<ReferenceTransmissionNo>")
        'Strpos2 = InStr(XmlRes, "</ReferenceTransmissionNo>")
        'Strposlen = Len("<ReferenceTransmissionNo>")
        Dt.Range("AO" & x) = Mid(XmlRes, (Strpos1 + Strposlen), (Strpos2 - (Strpos1 + Strposlen)))

    x = x + i
    Loop
    MsgBox ("Orders successfully uploaded")
End Sub
```

When I am executing it it is failing at Dt.Range("AO" & x) = Mid(XmlRes, (Strpos1 + Strposlen), (Strpos2 - (Strpos1 + Strposlen))) with an error Invalid Procedure call

"AO" is a column in the excel sheet. can anyone help me fix this

Comment: Please fix your code for complete code block. You have a `Loop` without `Do` and a `End Sub` without opening `Sub`, plus needed variables commented out.  Also, please post response XML as you should be using XPath or other DOM searches for parsing not string functions, `Instr` and `Mid`.

Comment: <otm:TransmissionAck xmlns:otm="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/otm/transmission/v6.4" xmlns:gtm="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/gtm/transmission/v6.4">
   <otm:EchoedTransmissionHeader>
      <otm:TransmissionHeader>
         <otm:SenderTransmissionNo>1234-AS</otm:SenderTransmissionNo>
         <otm:ReferenceTransmissionNo>12345678</otm:ReferenceTransmissionNo>
      </otm:TransmissionHeader>
   </otm:EchoedTransmissionHeader>
</otm:TransmissionAck>      This is the XMLresponse I am receiving of which I am trying to extract the value between the tags otm:ReferenceTransmissionNo how can I do

Comment: strpos1 = InStr(XmlRes, "<otm:ReferenceTransmissionNo>")
        strposlen = Len("<otm:ReferenceTransmissionNo>")
        strpos2 = InStr(XmlRes, "</otm:ReferenceTransmissionNo>")  strpos2 is not retrieving the exact position value anything wrong here?

Comment: Please edit your post with any data/code and then delete these hard to read comments. Also, I do not see VBA code fixes.